# Как отследить значение input range при перемещение ползунка без jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть input range

```
<input type="range" id="similarity" class="range" min="-1.0" max="1.0" value="0" step="0.1"></input>
```

нужно отслеживать его значение при перемещение ползунка

```
document.getElementById("similarity").onclick = function(){
console.log(document.getElementById("similarity").value)
```

Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const someInput = document.getElementById('someId')
const output1 = document.getElementById('output_1')
const output2 = document.getElementById('output_2')

someInput.addEventListener("input", onInputHandler);
someInput.addEventListener("change", onChangeHandler);

function onInputHandler(e) {
  output_1.innerText = `input: ${e.target.value}`
}

function onChangeHandler(e) {
  output_2.innerText = `change: ${e.target.value}`
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="someId" />

<h2 id="output_1"></h2>
<h2 id="output_2"></h2>
```

Comment: `textContent` лучше будет в этом случае, он быстрее :)